# Quectel EC25 Sending SMS and getting +CMS ERROR 305

Tags: c++, sms, gsm, quectel

This code sends some of SMS messages. But it gives error for some of the messages. It may about some wrong character that GSM module does not recognize like `(.
Is there any one can help to fix the code.
I am checking if GSM device is attached to ttyUSB2.
This is C++ code.

```
int sendSms(UsbPort &device, string phoneNumber, string message) {

    char buf[MAXBUF] = {0};
    int n;

    if(device.fildes > 0) {
        int max_check = 0;

        if (write(device.fildes, "ATZ\r", 4) < 4) {
            printf("ATZ write error - %s \n", strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }

        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

        if (write(device.fildes, "AT+CMGF=1\r", 10) < 10) {
            printf("AT+CMGF=1 write error - %s \n", strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }

        if (tcdrain(device.fildes) != 0) {
            perror("tcdrain() error");
            return -1;
        }

        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
        bzero(buf, sizeof(buf));
        read(device.fildes, buf, MAXBUF - 1);
        cout << "Buffer-1 = " << buf << endl;

        if (write(device.fildes, "ATE+CSMS=1\r", 11) < 11) {
            printf("ATE+CSMS=1 write error - %s \n", strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }

        if (tcdrain(device.fildes) != 0) {
            perror("tcdrain() error");
            return -1;
        }

        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
        bzero(buf, sizeof(buf));

        if ((n = read(device.fildes, buf, MAXBUF - 1)) > -1) {
            int length = strlen(buf);
            cout << "length = " << length << endl;
            buf[length] = '\0';
            cout << "Buffer-2 = " << buf << endl;
            if (strstr(buf, "+CSMS:") != NULL) { // Ready to send SMS
                cout << "Can send SMS: " + string(buf) << endl;
                // Send SMS
                string data1 = "AT+CMGS=\"" + phoneNumber + "\"\r";
                if (write(device.fildes, data1.c_str(), data1.length()) < data1.length()) {
                    printf("AT+CMGS write error - %s \n", strerror(errno));
                    return -1;
                }
                else {
                    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
                    string data2 = message + "\x1A";
                    if (write(device.fildes, data2.c_str(), data2.length()) < data2.length()) {
                        printf("ATE+CSMS=1 write error - %s \n", strerror(errno));
                        return -1;
                    }

                    if (tcdrain(device.fildes) != 0) {
                        perror("tcdrain() error");
                        return -1;
                    }

                    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
                    bzero(buf, sizeof(buf));
                    if ((n = read(device.fildes, buf, MAXBUF - 1)) > -1) {
                        int length = strlen(buf);
                        cout << "length = " << length << endl;
                        buf[length] = '\0';
                        cout << "Buffer-2 = " << buf << endl;
                        if (strstr(buf, "OK") != NULL) {
                            cout << message + " sent to : " + telNo + " successfully." << endl;
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << message + " sent to : " + telNo + " unsuccessful!" << endl;
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "Error: buf = " + string(buf) << endl;
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

this is the example of which it cannot send sms.

[image: The message that it does not send]

Comment: Actually `(` and `)` characters do belong to GSM charset. Could you please edit your question so that the output log is in text form instead of an image?

Comment: Please, post the entire output of `sendSMS` function. And, please, specify also: 1) how is `MAX_BUF` defined? Could you print separately the contents of `message` and also the value of `data2.length()`? What happens if you insert a shorted message, let's say the substring before `Alarm`?

Comment: Finally: could you post the response of the command `AT+CLAN?`.

Comment: We found the problem. It is not about ASCII characters. It is about message longer than it should be. We need to Send Sms as Concatenated SMS. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: It was exactly my assumption, that's why I asked those question in my previous comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not about ASCII characters, but about sending a message longer than it should be.

When we use *Concatenated SMS* it solved our problem. It Send Sms without problem.

```
AT+CGMF=1
AT+CSCS="GSM"
AT+CSMP=17,167,0,241
AT+CMGS="Number"
> Message <CTRL+Z>
```